# How can I represent an N dimensional line?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I represent a  straight line (between two points) in a N-dimensional space?

Comment: mind that a "line" is always $1$-dimensional, even if it sits in a $N$-dimensional space

Answer (score 9):

If $x,y$ are in $n$-dimensional space the line between them can be represented by $t(x-y)+y$ where $t$ runs over the real numbers. For a sanity check, observe that we get $y$ when $t=0$ and $x$ when $t=1$. You can't write a line as the solutions to a single equation in $n$ dimensions, unfortunately-you need $n-1$ equations, which is why you do get $y=mx+b$ etc in $2$ dimensions.

Comment: $t(x-y)+y$ do not represent nothing since it is not an equation!

Comment: Sure it does. It's the set of points given by each possible choice of $t$.

Comment: I think $t(x-y)+y=0$ would be that.

Comment: Nope, that's a set of infinitely many equations since $t$ varies. I mean exactly the set $\{1(x-y)+y,0(x-y)+y,1/2(x-y)+y,\pi(x-y)+y,...\}.$

Comment: Ah, OK. I understood now.

Comment: $\pi$ is not in the set

Answer (score 3):

You can take n-1 linearly independent hyperplanes which go through these two points and solve the system formed by those equations. The result will be the equation of the line.

I suppose that the form of the equation of the line could be:
$$\frac{x_1-x^0_1}{a_1}=\frac{x_2-x^0_2}{a_2}=...\frac{x_n-x^0_1}{a_n}$$
where $(x^0_1,x^0_2,...x^0_n)$ is a given point of the line and $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ a vector colinear to the line.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the first answer, we can represent a line in n-dimensions using vectors. An expression such as tv+u where v and u are n-dimensional vectors and t is a scalar. The vector v essential gives the inclination of the plane within n-space, and the vector u selects one out of an infinite number of planes that have the same inclination.