# Complex line in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

A complex line in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is defined to be a copy of $\mathbb{C}P^1$. I know that this determines an embedding which can be represented in the following way:
$$[u:v] \mapsto [ua_0+vb_0: \cdots :ua_n+vb_n]$$

where $[a_0:\cdots: a_n]$ and $[b_0:\cdots: b_n]$ are two points on $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

My questions are

1. Do we have another way of representing it? Like in the real case we have the expressions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703572/how-can-i-represent-an-n-dimensional-line).
2. How many points do we need to determine a line? Like in the real case we have two distinct points in any dimension determine a unique line. How do we see that?

Comment: Be careful. Your description of a complex line in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ as a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is incomplete. For example, one could regard a [twisted cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic) as a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ in $\mathbb{CP}^3$, but it is not a complex line. A complex line is a linearly embedded copy of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ in $\mathbb{CP}^n$.

Comment: Incidentally, 2 points in  $\mathbb{C}P^n$ will determine a line in $\mathbb{C}P^n$. (pun absolutely intended!)

Comment: What do you mean by $u_0, v_0, \dots, u_n, v_n$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry that was typo. Editted.

Comment: @EvansGambit Thanks for the editting! It's then clear that two points determines a line.

Comment: @EvansGambit I just wonder how do you see that this line is unique?

Comment: If you think about $\mathbb{C}P^n=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-0/\mathbb{C}^*$, then two distinct points $p, q\in \mathbb{C}P^n$, will correspond to  linearly independent vectors $v_p, v_q$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and the line $pq$ through them corresponds to the unique 2-dimensional subspace generated by  $v_p, v_q$.